# Private APIs used in iPhone screen sharing app

Tags: iphone, streaming, cydia, iphone-privateapi, screensharing

I'm curious about the [ScreenSplitr](http://screensplitr.com/) app for jail-broken iPhones. This app allows one to stream the phone's screen to a web browser. I can guess at how this works in general: capture the screen at a certain rate and forward the bytes over a socket to the destination device. **How can I determine which private APIs are used?**

I don't have a jail-broken phone. However I'll do it if that would help. Perhaps I can use a tool to examine the screensplitr binary and guess from there.

I'm assuming the use of private APIs since the app isn't in the app store. Perhaps the APIs aren't private (and the app was just rejected for "duplicate functionality" or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools such class-dump and otool that you can use to examine the mach-o files of the executable. The easiest thing is to use class-dump to get the headers of ScreenSplitr then go over those.